# Выделение памяти в dll, передача массива из dll и очистка памяти

Tags: c++, dll

Всем привет есть 2 вопроса:

1. Корректно ли так очищать память, как в коде если функция calc будет располагаться в отдельной dll? Если нет то как правильно? или есть ли другие варианты?
2. Почему в аргументах функции calc приходится писать именно ссылку на указатель Test *& test, а не Test * test?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   struct Test
   {
      int a;
      int b;
   };

    **// Эта функция будет в dll**

    void calc(Test *& test, unsigned int &sizeTest)
    {
    sizeTest = 3;

    test = new Test[sizeTest];

    for (uint i = 0; i < sizeTest; i++)
    {
    test[i].a = i;
    test[i].b = i;
    }
    }


   int main() 
   {
   Test *test = NULL;
   unsigned int sizeTest = 0;

   calc(test, sizeTest);

   cout << sizeTest << endl;

   for (uint i = 0; i < sizeTest; i++)
   {
   cout << test[i].a << endl;
   cout << test[i].b << endl;
   }

   // Корректно ли тут очищать память, выделенную в другой функции?
   delete[] test;

   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Если мененджер памяти гарантировано "общий" то можно. Но это редко встречается. А если у dll своя "куча"(heap) а у exe своя - то ясно ничего хорошего не будет. 2. При присвоении переменной типа `*&` ссылка `&` затронет пенеменную в вызвавшей функции (у вас это test), а без `&` ваша test окажется NULL.

Answer (score 4):

1. В общем случае так делать нельзя. Можно нарваться на проблемы. Память выделенную в dll надо освобождать в dll. Потому что менеджер памяти у процесса и dll может быть разный. Если так сильно надо выделять память в dll и передавать вызвавшему процессу, то можно в dll предусмотреть и функцию освобождения такой памяти, которую должен будет вызывать процесс.
2. Указатель - это переменная (ячейка памяти) хранящая адрес другой переменной. Параметры функции - это по сути отдельные временные переменные, которые создаются для каждого вызова функции, и которым присваиваются значения при её вызове, и которые существуют только на время работы функции. Поэтому чтобы изменить значение указателя с помощью функции, нужно чтобы параметр был ссылкой на этот указатель. На самом деле, внутренне, ссылка - это тоже указатель, просто синтаксис работы с ней - как с переменной. То есть когда ты передаешь ссылку на указатель, ты по сути передаешь указатель на указатель.
   А если ты просто передашь указатель не по ссылке, то ты передашь копию указателя, и эту копию внутри функции и изменишь - присвоишь ей значение адреса выделенной памяти.        А потом, при выходе из функции это копия просто пропадет.

Без ссылок ваша функция выглядела бы так:

```
void calc(Test ** test, uint * sizeTest)
{
   *sizeTest = 3;

   *test = new Test[*sizeTest];

   for (uint i = 0; i < *sizeTest; i++)
   {
       (*test)[i].a = i;
       (*test)[i].b = i;
   }
}

// использование
Test * array = nullptr;
uint   size  = 0;
calc(&array, &size);
```